# facebook graph api python -

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

This is my script to post a picture on my facebook page:

```
import facebook




def add_static_image_to_audio(text, media):
    page_access_token = "token"
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
    facebook_page_id = "1234567890"
    photo = open('example.jpg', 'rb')
    graph.put_object(facebook_page_id, "photos", message=text, file=photo.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Simple Python script to add a static image to an audio to make a video")
    parser.add_argument("text", help="The text")
    parser.add_argument("media", help="image")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    add_static_image_to_audio(args.text, args.media)
```

This error code occurs when i run the script above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\storage\app\fb.py", line 19, in <module>
    add_static_image_to_audio(args.text, args.media)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\storage\app\fb.py", line 11, in add_static_image_to_audio
    graph.put_object(facebook_page_id, "photos", message=text, file=photo)
  File "C:\Users\Linus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\facebook\__init__.py", line 189, in put_object
    return self.request(
  File "C:\Users\Linus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\facebook\__init__.py", line 313, in request
    raise GraphAPIError(result)
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#324) Requires upload file
```

How do i have to call the file so this problem stops occuring? The example.jpg used here is in the same directory as the script.

Comment: you show code with `file=photo.read()` but error shows `file=photo`. You show wrong code or you run wrong script.

Comment: it seems you use `laravel` - maybe you should find PHP module for working with Facebook. ie, [Facebook SDK for PHP](https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk)

Comment: it seems this module has [put_photo](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#put-photo) and maybe you should use it instead of `put_object`